# posting data to Elastic Search is becoming expensive

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, filebeat, elk

I am new to Elastic Search.I am using ES as a DB and Kibana as visualization tool.

I am posting data of my entire TEST suite to ES using bulk API.

But now I want to upload data of each test case to ES. But it is causing me to have multiple POST request.

Can somebody tell a way to do that

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

Comment: this is bulk api I think, but I dont want to update data in bulk. While using this, problem is that if I have say 10 test cases so by using bulk api those 10 cases are getting posted to ES in one go. So I wanted one test case to be uploaded at one time but this is causing me having multiple post requests.

Comment: can you describe the problem better? how the two cases are different?

Comment: 1st test case: Uploading 1 test case at time to ES.
2nd test case: Uploading 1 test suite consists of 10 test cases at time.
In 2nd case after whole suite is executed we will be able to see the logs in ES but I want to adopt 1st method in which after each test case, executed log will be sent to ES. Example: If my first test case fail, then I am not waiting for entire suite to execute.